# How to make mobile number validation in contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

How to create custom mobile number validation in Wordpress contact form 7 plugin is it possible please help me.
Actually i want to only valid  mobile number is allowed this field not taken any other character for ex- 9708644571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the phone number validation , you need to put the number field as per example given below.

```
[number* your-number min:9 max:10 step:3 class:required "40"]
```

Reference link : [CF7](https://contactform7.com/number-fields/)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Phone number validation : format and 10 digits
// Add code in your functions.php file 

function custom_contact_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {

       // 'contact': is name of tag in contact form

       if ( 'contact' == $tag->name ) {
           $re_format = '/^[0-9]{10}+$/';  //9425786311
           $your_contact = $_POST['contact'];

           if (!preg_match($re_format, $your_contact , $matches)) {
                $result->invalidate($tag, "Enter 10 digits only" );
           }

       }

       return $result;
 }

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_contact_validation_filter', 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_contact_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I don't understand this comment. // 'contact': is name of tag in contact form . In contact form 7, where can I find the tag name? Can't I just target the input field class name? If can, how should I call it?

Comment: We can add name to input field in contact form 7 while generating field

Comment: Worked a treat on a job i am working on now. Not a bad idea to strip out any spaces before running the preg_match:    
$your_contact = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['contact'] );

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom validation for mobile number, then you can use jQuery also.

Just like this:

```
$('.wpcf7-form .custom-field-class input').on('keypress', function(e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 43 || e.which > 57)) {
          return false;
     }
});
```

Place this file in your page template where form exists or in the footer.php or in your custom js file.

Please replace the `custom-field-class` with your input field wrapper class or you can modify your classes & inputs name according to your requirement.

Hope, this may be helpful to you.